# Styling Views created programmatically on Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view, android-inflate

So guys I was reading that it's simply not possible to set the style of a `view` via Java. There is no such method `myView.setStyle("styleName")` yet.

Then when you create your layout elements by code, such as `textvews`, and `imageviews` or `linearlayouts` as containers, how do you set their style? Do you assign rule by rule of each newly created element? Or is there a more efficient way to do this task?

@EDIT

Alright, I figured out how do it. Will answer my question with the solution I'm using

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass the view you want to style and pass the style you wish to apply during runtime. Something like the below class which simply sets a custom font to TextView. Mainly, you need to look into the 3rd constructor where you can supply your style.

```
public class TextViewRoboto extends TextView {

    public TextViewRoboto(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public TextViewRoboto(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setCustomFont(context, attrs);
    }

    public TextViewRoboto(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setCustomFont(context, attrs);
    }

    private void setCustomFont(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs) {
        setCustomFont(ctx, "roboto-light.ttf");
    }

    public boolean setCustomFont(Context ctx, String asset) {
        Typeface tf = null;
        try {
            tf = Typefaces.get(ctx, asset);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.e("Could not get typeface: " + e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }

        setTypeface(tf);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: and how do I reference the style? I mean, what should I pass to the constructor as defStyle? for example, if I have set a style 'myStyle' in the styles.xml, how should I use it in the constructor?

Comment: You can refer the style with R.style.myStyle. You need to replace the TextView element in your XML with the fully qualified name of your TextView's subclass !

Comment: @NitinSethi No you cannot. Look at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12683#c15

Answer (score 1):

Each View or its subclass has a third constructor that take the Style argument. For example, [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#View%28android.content.Context,%20android.util.AttributeSet,%20int%29) constructor of View. Mention the Style resource id for this view and thus it should be mentioned during view creation.

From documentation

> The default style to apply to this view. If 0, no style will be applied (beyond what is included in the theme). This may either be an attribute resource, whose value will be retrieved from the current theme, or an explicit style resource.

Answer (score 1):

**The solution I found** The goal is to create elements programmatically that were previously styled somewhere else.

First, I created a new XML file in the *res/layout* folder. I named it *template.xml* and inserted the following code in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    style="@style/rootElement"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/firstChildId"
        style="@style/firstChild" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/secondChild" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And then I styled then the way I wanted in *styles.xml* file

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="rootElement">
        <!-- style -->          
    </style>

    <style name="firstChild">
        <!-- style -->     
    </style>
</resources>
```

Now, in my Activity class I added:

```
LinearLayout rootElement = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.template, null);
someOtherView.addView(rootElement);
```

The inflater will load the template we created in res/layout/template.xml (all the elements in that file and its attributes) and assign it to `rootElement` that is then used in my code for anything else. Example

```
TextView firstChild = (TextView) rootElement.getChildAt(0);
firstChild.setText("It is the firstChild element");
```

or

```
TextView firstChild = (TextView) rootElement.findViewById(R.id.firstChildId);
...
```

Quite easy, isn't it?! I hope that helps

Comment: ... and how is this programmatically ? prijupaul's answer is correct. The catch: you can only apply a style when instantiating the view object/element, after that you can alter properties one-by-one, but can't apply a complete style.

Comment: this is what he means: new TextView(this, null, R.style.firstChild), then set the appropriate LayoutParams and you're done.

Comment: his answer may be correct (and I hope it helps other people). I am adding the solution I found/am using. this is 'programmatically' because the element was created in runtime and I and referring to an existing style. 

I created this tutorial because i found the examples quite difficult for beginners, and I saw some people with the same opinion commenting on the threads.

Comment: As an extra little kicker, you can apply a different Theme during view constuction/inflation by using a ContextWrapper. You would construct the ContextWrapper from your current Context, set the Theme in the ContextWrapper and user the ContextWrapper for inflating/constructing views. The contextWrapper will retrieve different styles/resources based on the theme.

Answer (score 0):

You can use themes and styles

A theme can be applied to the whole application by specifying the name of the theme in the Android manifest

e.g. `<application android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">`

You can override the theme for a specific activity by specifying a specific style.

There are various predefined themes Holo Light and Holo Dark are the more common themes. Most apps start by creating a new theme that is inherited from one of the above themes and overriding specific elements as needed.

The best thing to do really is to refer to the documentation, which should always be your first port of call.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Comment: His question is "Styling Views created programmatically on Android" and not through XML files.

Comment: @prijupaul  widgets created in code pick up the theme applied to the application declaration in the manifest. Styles can be applied in code as well as in XML, Themes and styles should be created as XML documents. So what's your point?